# Win 7 BSOD STOP: 0x0000007B

Tags: windows-7, bsod, infinite-loop

Stuck in a bootloop. Can't enter Safe-mode. The error I'm getting is a fraction of a second BSOD that I had to record with a phone and play back frame by frame to read, which is...

```
STOP: 0x0000007B (0xFFFFF880009A9928, 0XFFFFFFFFC0000034, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000)
```

Things I've already tried...

1. Start-up repair
2. [Bootrec.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927392/use-bootrec-exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues)

Don't want to do a clean install because I have a lot of app data and settings I can't possibly recreate.

I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: _that's why you do backups_

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2673509/you-receive-error-stop-error-code-0x0000007b-inaccessible-boot-device